# Graylog2 + Crowd LDAP

Tags: ldap, graylog, atlassian-crowd

I want to integrate Graylog2 (v1.1.2) with Atlassian Growd LDAP server (v2.8.3).

Now all users can login into Graylog but I want to permit only users witch has group "graylog-users".

My settings:

**Search Base DN:** ou=users,dc=crowd

**User Search Pattern:** (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0}))

My LDAP structure example:

```
dc=crowd
   ou=groups
      dn=graylog-users
         objectClass=groupOfName
         objectClass=top
         cn=graylog-users
         member=dn=user1,ou=users,dc=crowd
         member=dn=user1,ou=users,dc=crowd
         businesCategory
         description
         anotherFiedls
      dn=jira-administrators
      dn=jira-developers
      dn=jira-users
   ou=users
      dn=user1
         objectClass=organizationalPerson
         objectClass=person
         objectClass=inetOrgPerson
         objectClass=top
         cn=Firstname Lastname
         sn=Lastname
         givenname=Firstname
         ou=users
         uid=user1    
      dn=user2
         objectClass=organizationalPerson
         objectClass=person
         objectClass=inetOrgPerson
         objectClass=top
         cn=Firstname Lastname
         sn=Lastname
         givenname=Firstname
         ou=users
         uid=user2
      dn=user3
         objectClass=organizationalPerson
         objectClass=person
         objectClass=inetOrgPerson
         objectClass=top
         cn=Firstname Lastname
         sn=Lastname
         givenname=Firstname
         ou=users
         uid=user3
```

How I can do it?